# Two dimensional matrix using for loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, matrix

I want to make the following matrix using loops:

```
matrix = [[x - 3 , y - 3], [ x - 2 , y - 3], [x - 1, y - 3], [ x , y - 3],
               [x - 3, y - 2], [x - 2, y - 2], [x - 1, y - 2], [x, y - 2],
               [x - 3, y - 1], [x - 2, y - 1], [x - 1, y - 1], [x, y - 1],
               [x - 3, y], [x - 2, y ], [x - 1, y ], [x, y],
               [x - 3, y + 1], [x - 2, y + 1], [x - 1, y + 1], [x, y + 1],
               [x - 3, y + 2], [x - 2, y + 2], [x - 1, y + 2], [x, y + 2],
               [x - 3, y + 3], [x - 2, y + 3], [x - 1, y + 3], [x, y + 3]]
```

such that when if I want to increase constant from 3 to 5 or any number it automatically creates this matrix accordingly. It is 7x4 matrix. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: first try, later show us error message.

Comment: `for column in range(-3, 1):`

Comment: `for row in range(-3, 3+1)`

Comment: What you show in the question is a 28 x 2 matrix with two parameters.  The line breaks are irrelevant to the structure of the list of lists.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Not exactly. But with the help of the posted answers I managed to get what I wanted. Thanks for your answer too :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) -

```
r,c = np.ogrid[x-3:x+1, y-3:y+4]
out = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(r,c))
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [114]: x,y = 0,0

In [115]: out.tolist() # Showing as list
Out[115]: 
[[[-3, -3], [-2, -3], [-1, -3], [0, -3]],
 [[-3, -2], [-2, -2], [-1, -2], [0, -2]],
 [[-3, -1], [-2, -1], [-1, -1], [0, -1]],
 [[-3, 0], [-2, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[-3, 1], [-2, 1], [-1, 1], [0, 1]],
 [[-3, 2], [-2, 2], [-1, 2], [0, 2]],
 [[-3, 3], [-2, 3], [-1, 3], [0, 3]]]
```

You can also use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) that would produce `X's` and `Y's` swapped -

```
np.dstack(np.mgrid[y-3:y+4, x-3:x+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
>>> def compute(x,y):
...     return [[x+j, y+i] for i in range(-3,4) for j in range(-3,1)]
...
>>> print compute(0,0)
[[-3, -3], [-2, -3], [-1, -3], [0, -3], [-3, -2], [-2, -2], [-1, -2], [0, -2], [-3, -1], [-2, -1], [-1, -1], [0, -1], [-3, 0], [-2, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [-3, 1], [-2, 1], [-1, 1], [0, 1], [-3, 2], [-2, 2], [-1, 2], [0, 2], [-3, 3], [-2, 3], [-1, 3], [0, 3]]
```